# Graphical list of all ASP.NET 6.0 Blazor oi- icons

Tags: asp.net-core

In "Shared/NavMenu.razor", there are icons used like `oi-home` or `oi-plus`. Is there a page where I can see all those icons and names?

I searched Google and found https://icons.getbootstrap.com/ , but that site does not represent the icons in a ASP.NET Blazor project, because, for example, if I search the site for "download", it shows

[image]

but in VS, the autocomplete list shows only two, and "data-transfer-download" does not exist on the website above.

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Blazor is using Open Iconic v1.1.1 not Bootstrap icons and I think it is not maintained anymore. Here is the GitHub repo - https://github.com/iconic/open-iconic - the site useiconic.com no longer works.

You find the icon list here - https://www.appstudio.dev/app/OpenIconic.html